# Asp.Net Core 3.1 App sets the wrong runtimeOptions

Tags: .net-core-3.1, azure-webapps

I am developing a quick ASP.Net Core 3.1 app, and trying to push it to a Free Linux-hosted WebApp in Azure. 
The app builds, runs locally, and deploys to a docker environment in Windows Azure. All the files are deployed as expected.

The challenge is this:

Upon starting the app using the command

```
dotnet <mywebproject>.dll
```

The log tells me this:

> *The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.*

First thing to check was to see if there was a missing runtime

```
root@4182491:~/site/wwwroot# dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

After some fondling, I see that there is a file named **.runtimeconfig.json**:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

So the runtime I ***need*** is there, but dotnet does not want to select it!

From the error, I am *assuming* that dotnet is attempting to start the website using the first framework that it can see, however how do I get rid of it during build? I've looked up how these files get generated during build, and can see no options to *prevent* a framework from being put into the runtimeOptions file.

Since I am building the app using Azure DevOps, I can't simply edit the file manually and upload it to the hosted linux container that it runs in.

So I need help with either:

- How to build the project and EXCLUDE "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" from the list of frameworks being generated
- How to START the application in the linux container with a specific target framework NAME (I can only choose version from the settings I see in **dotnet exec** using SSL to the container.

This is more or less driving me nuts!

Comment: Shot in the dark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158973

Comment: Yup, that's not it. The runtime IS there, but for some reason, dotnet chooses to go with the non-compatible one

Comment: Could you share the properties of your csproj? and more specifically the `RuntimeIdentifiers` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer this one myself, since I found the solution after way too much coffee:

Turns out that the **options** you see here:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Aren't options at all, but **requirements**. I found a dependency on a package designed for WPF that of course requires the *Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App* runtime to be installed. Since I'm developing on a windows computer, the code had all the necessary runtimes to run in debug, but not on linux.

I'll close this for now, but since the naming led to confusion, I will leave the question up in case someone else runs into the same confusion that I did.